# Manual install of R-package "xlsReadWrite" on OS X

Tags: r, excel, macos

I'm having trouble with manual install of an R-package called "xlsReadWrite."  I know there are other packages available that can read Excel or csv files in to R, but I need to use this specific package as it is integrated in various places of a quite long script I want to use.

I'm using R-Studio Version 0.98.1091 on a Mac OS X (10.10.3)

The package is no longer available on CRAN, but there's a zip file available online here:

http://www.swissr.org/download

I can manually install the package but then when I hit the check mark I get the following error output:

> library("xlsReadWrite", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library")

Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘xlsReadWrite.so’ not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsReadWrite’

I don't know quite how to interpret this.  Does anyone have a way of successfully installing this package?  Thanks a million in advance!!!

Ben

Comment: Try installing it from source. Try `library(devtools); install_github("swissr/xlsreadwrite")`.

Comment: I've found a solution.  There are 2 things to necessary to know: 1.) The package "xlsReadWrite" is a Windows-only package.  2.)  The file format that is needed to do a manual install is "tar.gz", and can be found here: http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/xlsReadWrite/ for version 1.5.4 of the package.  This solution worked on my Windows computer (OS Windows 7 Professional).  The newest version (1.5.5) on the SwissR site linked above did not work for me.

Comment: I tried installing the swissr version but it's not designed for 64 bit systems.